# VSCode says there is no module 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

I just installed matplotlib onto my Windows computer using Pip and entering the following into the command prompt:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Everything has been installed correctly from the looks of it, but after opening up VSCode, the following line gives me a problem still:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Every time I try to run my program I get this printed to the console:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Not sure what to do here as I thought I had matplotlib installed correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you selected the correct python interpreter in VS Code? (look bottom left) There might be more than one python interpreter and you may happen to install matplotlib to another and using the one without matplotlib installed.

Comment: @IbrahimBerber That's exactly what I was doing wrong. Just had to switch to the interpreter installed on my machine. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.  I'm running windows 10 and VS Code ver. 1.79.2.

So, I had to:

1. setup my path to python, using a command prompt with 'where python' to verify the correct path.
2. then putting that path under environment variables 'PATH'.
3. Next I ran a terminal inside VS Code with this command: 'pip install matplotlib', then everything got downloaded, installed, and resolved.

I like happy endings!